# using global variables to encode and decode morse using a list of morsecode

Tags: python, global-variables

Basically I have to make a morse code encoder and decoder using two functions. My professor's template (and of course I have added code to the first function and main function) includes a global variable and I have no idea how to use it. Also I am getting an error for the current code because the letter is somehow an integer not a string letter. Can someone just explain how I could use the global variable in this program, because I am not worried about the errors right now?

```
MORSE_CODES=[' .- ',' -... ',' -.-. ',' -.. ',' . ',' ..-. ',' --. ',' .... ',' .. ',
' .--- ',' -.- ',' .-.. ',' -- ',' -. ',' --- ',' .--. ',' --.- ',' .-. ',
' ... ',' - ',' ..- ',' ...- ',' .-- ',' -..- ',' -.-- ',' --.. ']

ASCII_A=65 #global var




def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg_Morse=(my_msg.upper())
  my_msg_Morse=my_msg_Morse.replace(" ","   ")
 
  
  for letter in range(0, len(my_msg_Morse)):
    
    if ord(letter)>=65 and ord(letter)<=90:
      my_msg_Morse=my_msg_Morse.replace(letter, MORSE_CODES[letter])
    else:
      my_msg_Morse=my_msg_Morse.replace(letter,'*')
    my_msg_Morse=my_msg_Morse+" "+letter
  return my_msg_Morse

**#def decode_Morse(my_msg):
my_msg_Morse=my_msg.split("    ")
  string=""
  for word in my_msg_Morse:**


def main():
  my_msg=input("Enter your message: ")
  my_msg=my_msg.upper()
  print("Your message in plain text: ", my_msg)
  
  my_msg_Morse=encode_Morse(my_msg)
  print("Your message in Morse Code: ", my_msg_Morse)
```

Comment: Why are you using range? To iterate over all the characters in a string you should do `for letter in my_msg_Morse:`. There are other errors in your code such as `MORSE_CODES[letter])`. `MORSE_CODES` is a list and should be indexed by an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `for letter in range(0, len(my_msg_Morse)):` does not loop over letters in message
2. `my_msg_Morse=my_msg_Morse.replace(letter, MORSE_CODES[letter])` causes replacement of Morse code letters in messages with spaces (i.e. multiple word messages)
3. Regarding globals -- just use them if you only need to use their values (which you are here)

**Code**

```
MORSE_CODES=[' .- ',' -... ',' -.-. ',' -.. ',' . ',' ..-. ',' --. ',' .... ',' .. ',
' .--- ',' -.- ',' .-.. ',' -- ',' -. ',' --- ',' .--. ',' --.- ',' .-. ',
' ... ',' - ',' ..- ',' ...- ',' .-- ',' -..- ',' -.-- ',' --.. ']

ASCII_A=65 #global var

def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  result = ''
  for letter in my_msg_Morse:
    if 65 <= ord(letter) <= 90:
      if not result:
          result = MORSE_CODES[ord(letter)-ASCII_A]          # first Morse character
      else:
          result += ' ' + MORSE_CODES[ord(letter)-ASCII_A] # space between Morse character
    else:
      result += '*' 
    
  return result

def decode_Morse(my_msg):
    for i, code in enumerate(MORSE_CODES):
        my_msg = my_msg.replace(code, chr(i+65))
  
    return my_msg.replace('*', ' ')

def decode_Morse_using_counter(my_msg):
    ' Version using counter rather than enumerate to track index '
    i = 0
    for code in MORSE_CODES:
        my_msg = my_msg.replace(code, chr(i+65))
        i += 1
  
    return my_msg.replace('*', ' ')

def main():
  my_msg = input("Enter your message: ")
  my_msg = my_msg.upper().replace(' ', '   ')  # upper case with 3 letters between words
  print("Your message in plain text: ", my_msg)
  encode_msg = encode_Morse(my_msg)
  print("Your message in Morse Code: ", encode_msg)
  print("Decoded Morse Code: ", decode_Morse(encode_msg))

main()
```

**Example Run**

```
Enter your message: This is a simple message
Your message in plain text:  THIS   IS   A   SIMPLE   MESSAGE
Your message in Morse Code:   -  ....  ..  ... *** ..  ... *** .- *** ...  ..  --  .--.  .-..  . *** --  .  ...  ...  .-  --.  . 
Decoded Morse Code:  THIS   IS   A   SIMPLE   MESSAGE
```

**Function Rewrite**

Using list comprehension and Walrus operator, the encode_Morse function can be reduced to:

```
def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg_Morse = my_msg.upper()
  return ''.join(MORSE_CODES[p-ASCII_A] if 65 <=(p:=ord(letter))<= 90 else '*' for letter in my_msg_Morse)
```

Comment: thank you, am I going on the right track for the decode_morse function?

Comment: @qwvst--did this help with the encode function?

Comment: @qwvst--not sure what function you are referring in the question: "so i do not need the global function in the decode function".  The decode_Morse is the decode function.  It makes use of the dictionary I created REVERSE_CODE which consists of the morse code letters.  Do you see how the decode_Morse works?

Comment: ok i just saw where you defined the REVERSE FUNCTION. The code seems kind of complicated as I am a beginner and I have not learning about dictionaries yet. I tried to understand but i dont get it, thank you for your help

Comment: @qwvst--the dictionary is used to associate each Morse code sequence to a letter.  To decode we start from the first letter.  We take successive dashes & dots until the sequence maps to a letter (A-Z).  Then we start the process over again.

Comment: Initialize text_string to empty string
Stopping Condition: All codes in MORSE_CODES have been decoded in string Loop Body: Consider each code in MORSE_CODES
Replace code in text_string with the appropriate letter for code
Replace three spaces in text_string with single space to separate words Output text_string     >>>This is the design which I came up with, if you can help me make the code simpler]

Comment: @qwvst--updated the decoder based upon your suggestion.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I just looked up what enumerate does, its basically a counter. So can you do a manual counter instead ?

Comment: @qwvst--yes you can easily use a counter.  Do you need help with that or does it seem straightforward?  But, you should become familiar with `enumerate` since it is the Pythonic approach for looping through a list with an index for each element.  `enumerate is so popular that anyone reviewing your code would question why you're not using it if you tried to use a counter.

Comment: Yes, please I not exactly sure where to place the code. Also, what two things are you looping through? Is it each character and each word in the string?

Comment: @qwvst--added a version that uses counter rather than enumerate i.e. decode_Morse_using_counter.  A reminder is this answer was useful  don't forget to [accept nswer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: One last thing, for formating I need to have three spaces between each word and one space between morse characters, and * if its not in dictionary. Do I need an elif statement that converts the one space into three spaces for the spaces between the words

Comment: @qwvst--modified encode_Morse and main functions.  Does the latest output correspond to what you want?

Comment: I got it, i really appreciate your help and quick response on this! thank and I have accepted the answer:)